# Enable/Disable xDebug through Docker-Compose, is it possible?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        zlib1g-dev \
        git \
        unzip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip pdo_mysql bcmath \
    && a2enmod rewrite \
    && pecl install xdebug-2.9.0 redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug redis \
    && mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini" \
    && mv /var/www/html /var/www \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/ \
    && ln -s /usr/local/bin/php /usr/bin/php
COPY --from=composer:1.9 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
WORKDIR /var/www/drm-case
CMD ["docker/apache/bootstrap.sh"]
```

And this is the `docker-compose.yml` file that uses the previous `Dockerfile` to build the containers (not all the time though):

```
version: "2.4"

services:
  case-v2-apache:
    container_name: local-dev
    image: local-dev:1.6 # increase this number when changing the Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      mysql-server:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ${LOCAL_PATH}:/var/www:delegated
      - ${LOCAL_PATH}/docker/apache/conf.d:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
      - ${LOCAL_PATH}/docker/apache/conf-enabled/servername.conf:/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/servername.conf
      - ${LOCAL_PATH}/docker/apache/sites-available/000-default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
    ports:
      - "8009:80"
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    build:
      context: ${LOCAL_PATH:-./local-dev}
      dockerfile: docker/apache/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - main
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=local-dev.localhost
      - COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1
      - COMPOSER_AUTH=${COMPOSER_AUTH}
      - COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
      - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=local-dev
```

One of the files being copied in this line: `${LOCAL_PATH}/docker/apache/conf.d:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d` is xdebug related meaning is the one enabling and setting up the extension.

Wonder if there is a way to tell Docker by using `ARG` or `ENV` variables to enable/disable xDebug while starting the container? Has anyone tried such thing before? If so can you help me with some ideas?

Comment: You could use different docker-compose files to mount the specific config file which installs xdebug extension and start it with `docker-compose -f custom.yml up -d`. Or you could use a legacy feature called extends which allows you to use env variables to customize what file you mount - https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/. Major downside is that this feature was deprecated in version 2.1 i believe.

Comment: Have you considered manipulating your `xdebug.ini` config file (e.g. commenting out or not the `zend_extension=...` directive, moving the file to *.back...) from your entrypoint script based on the presence/value of an ENV var ?

Answer (score 3):

You could simply move/rename the xdebug conf file based on a build arg…

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        zlib1g-dev \
        git \
        unzip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip pdo_mysql bcmath \
    && a2enmod rewrite \
    && pecl install xdebug-2.9.0 redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug redis \
    && mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini" \
    && mv /var/www/html /var/www \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/ \
    && ln -s /usr/local/bin/php /usr/bin/php
COPY --from=composer:1.9 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN if [[ "$DISABLE_XDEBUG" == "1" ]] ; then mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/xdebug.ini" "$PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/xdebug.ini.disabled"

WORKDIR /var/www/drm-case
CMD ["docker/apache/bootstrap.sh"]
```

… or something like that?